# Invoking ShellSettingsManager in Constructor throw System.UnsupportedException. How to fix this?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I have below code in one of the class library project built with Target Framework is .net 4.6.2.
and I am trying to instantiate it in other class library (same .net framework) by adding project reference, it throws exception on First line of Constructor.

**IDE Version:** VS 2017
**Nuget Version:** Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.14.0

```
Public My_Constructor()

{
            SettingsManager settingsManager = new ShellSettingsManager(ServiceProvider.GlobalProvider);
            this.store = settingsManager.GetWritableSettingsStore(SettingsScope.UserSettings);
            this.store.CreateCollection(CollectionPath);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my research, I find that the code is not appropriate for the class library(.net framework 4.6.2).

The code is used for using the Settings Store and it requires a VSIX project. You could refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/using-the-settings-store?view=vs-2019).